# You can't resubscribe after accidentally unsubscribing from emails

Tags: bug, status-review, email

I was going through some unwanted emails in my inbox and I had one from Stack Overflow about the 2019 Survey, and there was an email right above the SO email in my inbox which was the one I *wanted* to unsubscribe from.

I accidentally clicked on the SO email and without paying attention I scrolled to the bottom of the email and clicked the "Unsubscribe from emails like this".

This lead me to the email settings page where it flashed the section I had just unsubscribed from like this:
[image]

After realizing my mistake I tried clicking the "On" toggle and nothing happened. I opened dev tools and I see these errors every time I click the "On" button:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
>
> jquery.min.js:4 POST
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/subscribe/some-redacted-personal-info
>   403

Browser: Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Obviously the easy fix was to click out of this page and get back to the email settings through my profile and then I could toggle it once again.